# Find numbers in Python list which are within a certain distance of each other

Tags: python, list, filter, sequence

I have a list of numbers in Python.  It looks like this:

```
a = [87, 84, 86, 89, 90, 2014, 1000, 1002, 997, 999]
```

I want to keep all the numbers which are within + or - 7 of each other and discard the rest.  Is there a simple way to do this in Python?  I have read about the list filter method but am not sure how to get what I want working with it.

I am new to Python.

**Update**

Output would ideally be [84, 86, 87, 89, 90] and another list [997, 999, 1000, 1002].  I want to retrieve the sequences and not the outliers.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: what is ur expected output of above list

Comment: Output would ideally be [84, 86, 87, 89, 90] and another list [997, 999, 1000, 1002]

Comment: Please update your question with the expected output. Is there a minimal size of that list? If no `[2014]` would be a solution too.

Comment: how to find which is middle element ..like 87 . we have to consider first element as middle element when v start searching.

Comment: what about such a list: [2,5,8,10,12]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is algorithm problem, try this:

```
def get_blocks(values):
    mi, ma = 0, 0
    result = []
    temp = []
    for v in sorted(values):
        if not temp:
            mi = ma = v
            temp.append(v)
        else:
            if abs(v - mi) < 7 and abs(v - ma) < 7:
                temp.append(v)
                if v < mi:
                    mi = v
                elif v > ma:
                    ma = v
            else:
                if len(temp) > 1:
                    result.append(temp)
                mi = ma = v
                temp = [v]
    return result

a = [87, 84, 86, 89, 90, 2014, 1000, 1002, 997, 999]
print get_blocks(a)
```

Output:

```
[[84, 86, 87, 89, 90], [997, 999, 1000, 1002]]
```

Answer (score 2):

For any problem like this my first port of call is the [Python itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).  The *pairwise* function from that link that I use in the code is available in the [more-itertools module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools).

```
from more_itertools import pairwise
results = []
chunk = []
a = [87, 84, 86, 89, 90, 2014, 1000, 1002, 997, 999]
a.sort()
for v1, v2 in pairwise(a):
    if v2 - v1 <= 7:
        chunk.append(v1)
    elif chunk:
        chunk.append(v1)
        results.append(chunk)
        chunk = []
print(results)
[[84, 86, 87, 89, 90], [997, 999, 1000, 1002]]
```

I haven't tested for edge cases, so it's buyer beware :)

Answer (score 1):

If your problems allows transitive relations, i.e. x is in the group as long as it's at most 7 away from *any* element in the group, then this seems to me like a [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) problem. To be more specific, you need to find all [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).

The problem itself is pretty easy to solve with a recursive algorithms. You would first create a dictionary in which every key would be one of the elements and every value would be a list of elements which are at most 7 apart from that element. For your example, you would have something like this:

```
for element in elements:
    connections[element] = []
    visited[element] = False
    for another in elements:
        if abs(element - another) <= limit:
            connections[element].append(another)
```

Which would give you something like this

```
{
    84: [86, 87, 89, 90],
    86: [84, 87, 89, 90],
    ...
    997: [999, 1000, 1002]
    ...
    2014: []
}
```

Now you need to write a recursive function which will take as input an element and a list, and it will keep adding elements in a list as long as it can find an element which is at most 7 apart from the current element.

```
def group_elements(element, group):
    if visited[element]:
        return
    visited[element] = True
    group.append(element)
    for another in connections[element]:
        group_elements(another, group)
```

Somewhere in the code you also need to remember which elements you have already visited to make sure that you don't get into an infinite loop.

```
visited = {}
```

You need to call that function for every element in your list.

```
groups = []
for element in elements:
    if not visited[element]:
        group = []
        group_elements(element, group)
        groups.append(group)
print group
```

This code should give the following output for your input:

```
[[87, 84, 86, 89, 90], [2014], [1000, 1002, 997, 999]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [87, 84, 86, 89, 90, 2014, 1000, 1002, 997, 999]
temp=a[0]
result=[]
temp1=[]
counter =len(a)

for i in a:
    if i in range(temp-7,temp+7):
        temp1.append(i)
        if counter==1:
            result.append(temp1)
    else:
        if temp1:
            result.append(sorted(temp1))
        temp1=[]
        temp=i
    counter=counter-1
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Say, we have a list `aa = [87, 84, 86, 89, 90, 2014, 1000, 1002, 997, 999]`.

```
aa = sorted(aa)
aa
[84,86,87,89,90,997,999,1000,1002,2014]
```

To define differences among neighbors: `ad = np.ediff1d(aa)`.

```
ad
array([2, 1, 2, 1, 907, 2, 1, 2, 1012])
```

To cut off indices of numbers beyond the range:
`np.where(ad > rng)[0] + 1`, where `rng = 7` is range within which the numbers are kept:

```
np.where(ad > 7)[0] + 1
array([5, 9])
```

To split the array by indices into required subarrays:
`np.split(aa, np.where(ad > rng)[0] + 1)`. So, the function is:

```
def splitarr(aa,rng):
    ad = np.ediff1d(aa)
    return np.split(aa, np.where(ad > rng)[0] + 1)

splitarr(aa, 7)    
[array([84, 86, 87, 89, 90]), array([ 997,  999, 1000, 1002]), array([2014])]
```

The length of allowable sequence could be set by the filter:

```
np.where(np.fromiter(map(len, splarr), dtype=int) >= lim)[0]
```

where `splarr = np.split(aa, np.where(ad > rng)[0] + 1)`.
That returns indices of arrays of allowed length. map(len, splarr) returns lengths of all arrays inside list `splarr`; `np.fromiter()` converts `map` to `numpy` to enable `>= lim`. `lim` is the threshold for array length, only this length and above is OK. So, the final function is:

```
def splitarr(aa,rng,lim):
    splarr = np.split(aa, np.where(np.ediff1d(aa) > rng)[0] + 1)
    return [splarr[i] for i in np.where(np.fromiter(map(len, splarr), dtype=int) >= lim)[0]]

splitarr(aa, 7, 2)
[array([84, 86, 87, 89, 90]), array([ 997,  999, 1000, 1002])]
splitarr(aa,7,1)
[array([84, 86, 87, 89, 90]), array([ 997,  999, 1000, 1002]), array([2014])] 
splitarr(aa, 1, 1)
[array([84]), array([86, 87]), array([89, 90]), array([997]), array([ 999, 1000]), array([1002]), array([2014])]
splitarr(aa,1,2)
[array([86, 87]), array([89, 90]), array([ 999, 1000])]
splitarr(aa,2,2)
[array([84, 86, 87, 89, 90]), array([ 997,  999, 1000, 1002])]
```

**Instead of a comment under the 'best answer':** it works only with the range 7, and is incorrect for any other value.